# Execute JavaSCript code after image preload

Tags: javascript, preload

I'm trying to create some kind of callback code which gets executed after an image has been preloaded.

My JS code is as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
d=document;
window.onload=function()
{
   if (d.images)
   {
      d.getElementById('preload').style.display='block';
      i1=new Image;
      i1.src="http://link_to_image";
      d.getElementById('preload').style.display='none';
   }
}
</script>
```

So in my example, `d.getElementById('preload').style.display='none';` should be executed after the image has been fully loaded into the cache.

Any help on how to achieve this? Please only standalone JavaScript solutions without library/plugin requirements.

Comment: I just found out that `setInterval("if(i1.complete){...}", 500)` is a good solution.

Edit: But not as good as the suggested solutions below.

Comment: Yeah, you should avoid the string argument to `setInterval`/`setTimeout`; pass a `function() { ... }` in instead in preference. Also there's no `complete` attribute, only `readyState` (and that's non-standard, so `onload` is still best). Also you can probably lose the `if (document.images)` test, as the last browser not to support it was Netscape 2! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how reliable the image `onload` event is in all browsers, so I'd test this very carefully:

```
var i1 = new Image();

i1.onload = function() {
   d.getElementById('preload').style.display = "none";
};

i1.src = "http://link_to_image";
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article, i think it will help: [link text](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5214317.html)

> like many other objects in JavaScript, the Image() object also comes with some event handlers. The most useful of these is undoubtedly the onLoad() handler, which is invoked when the image has completed loading.

Answer (score 1):

Use onload in the image tag itself.

```
<img src="http://link_to_image" onload="alert('IMG LOADED')" />
```